q-series Expansion at Cusp and L-Functions
We know that the coefficients at $\infty$ of a modular form that is an eigenfunction of all Hecke operators in, say, $\Gamma_0(q)$, give an $L$-function with an Euler product and a functional equation. I'm wondering what can be said about the coefficients of the same modular form but at a different cusp. For instance, when $q$ is prime the cusps are $\infty$ and $0$. Does the $q$-expansion of the function at $0$ still produce an interesting $L$-function?
Thanks in advance for any help!

Yes, it does. You should look up the Fricke involution (for the cusp $0$) and more generally Atkin-Lehner operators (for other cusps, at least if $q$ is squarefree).

When $q$ is prime, the expansion at the $0$ cusp will either be equal to the expansion at $\infty$ or $-1$ times the expansion at $\infty$. In greater generality, the expansion at a cusp of general level will be the expansion at $\infty$ of a different modular form (of perhaps higher level).
